# Status of a date powerbuilder

Tags: validation, date, status, powerbuilder

I have two columns in a row. First is registration_date and the second is closing_date. When I change the closing_date I set a status variable in 1, if closing_date is unchanged status is 0. I've tried to do that in itemchanged event, but it works if only I change the closing_date. If I don't, nothing happens.
So, my question is how do I check if the closing_date is the old one or a new one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set the status to 0 when you populate the datawindow with your data.  Itemchanged is triggered by a change to a column in the datawindow, not when the data is initially retrieved from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the GetItemStatus function?